# data type validation error on migrating to sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, etl

We have migrated some of our SSIS packages from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016 version. I am now working with `Visual Studio 2015` to edit these packages and test.

When I download the packages from `catalog/project` via the `SSIS Import Export Wizard` option, I get validation errors on all packages upon opening them where they are using OLE DB source/destination editor. The error specifically is to do with data type, for example:

> Column "NAME" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

Opening the same package from legacy 2008 server in Visual Studio 15, I see no such errors.

The data type seem to convert from string to Unicode string [DT_WSTR].

Does anybody know what is the cause of this?

When I switch the provider in my `Connection String` from `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1` to `Provider=MSDAORA.1` the validation errors are gone. I am trying to understand what could be missing in my local environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2015 is 32-bit. To work with design mode...I needed to install Oracle Client 11g 32 Bit as well as 64 bit.